# Where can I exchange Zambian Kwacha in the UK?

Tags: uk, money, exchange, zambia

I came back from a work trip with approximately 1200 Zambian Kwacha (~£45). I don't think most banks will take it. Any ideas where I can exchange it for GBP in the UK?

Answer (score 2):

There is **cash4coinsuk** at [this site](https://www.cash4coins.co.uk/payment-exchange-rates/) who operate from Poole, UK.

They offer to exchange coins and notes of all currencies, including Zambia Kwacha.

<sub>(No affiliation or dealings).</sub>

Comment: I do not know that particual processor, but my warning bells start to chime when they don't list their currency exchange rates on the web page. They rather want you to send them your notes and coins and *then* they will make an offer. I would not expect a very good deal, but exchanging Zambian currency in UK might not be a good deal anywhere.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I wondered what the deal would be too. There are some weasel words about how good they are, but then how bad they might be. Still, if I can find one, OP might find another.