# Exchange Options for Zambian Kwacha (ZMW) to British Pounds (GBP) in Bristol?

Tags: uk, money, exchange, zambia, bristol

I have 47150 Zambian Kwacha money and want to exchange it into GBP.

Where can I exchange it? Does anyone know? I already asked No 1 exchange currency, but they do not exchange this currency. Please let me know where can I exchange it. Currently, I am living in Bristol.

Comment: Have you tried the larger banks in Bristol?

Comment: This [previous question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/161034/where-can-i-exchange-zambian-kwacha-in-the-uk) is sort of a dupe, but given the red flags the exchange site raises, I'm hesitant to suggest it as dupe.  Also the site in question no longer mentions Kwacha

Comment: See also [Changing unusual foreign currencies in London](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1596/changing-unusual-foreign-currencies-in-london), though I guess it's not strictly a duplicate if you can't get to London.

Comment: mlc's [Changing unusual foreign currencies in London](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1596/changing-unusual-foreign-currencies-in-london) does have a postal option, so it's worth looking at.

Answer (score 10):

The Zambian kwacha is too minor and inflationary for most companies in the UK to want to deal with.  Your best bet would probably to reach out directly to the Zambian community in the UK via groups like [Zambians Together](https://www.zambianstogether.org/), they can either point the way or you can find somebody to negotiate a private exchange with.   Although I'm afraid that living in Bristol instead of London will complicate things.

Answer (score 3):

Zambian Kwacha is not supported by the regular travel currency exchanges or the [UK postal office](https://www.postoffice.co.uk/foreign-currency). You may want to try one of the larger commercial banks or major hotel chains, but you should probably expect the same result. If they do agree to accept your currency - expect significant fees.